# How can download files from longblob mysql without (extension,type,size) fields

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, blob

I searched a lot about how to download files from longblob mysql but all the code requests (extension,type,size) and i do not make These fields and i do not want make it . SO, Is there any way to download any file type (jpg,gif,pdf,png,txt,ect..) from the database without (extension,type,size) fields ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to save a file in your database. It's an old tradition. Try to come outside. Save the file in the directory and after that save the file name or path in the database. This will decrease the load on the database and also decrease unusual use of the db storage

Answer (score 0):

A couple things here:

- Do NOT store files in the database. The database is for data, the
  file system is for files.  The smart way to do something like this is
  to have a varchar storing `/path/to/your/file.foo`
- Unless you plan to examine each file (costly and slow), you benefit GREATLY from just storing this data for re-use in the future

Comment: thanks for ur answer , I know that already my friend but now i just want a way to download files from the database not from the folder - surely there is a way to do that .

Comment: you still aren't listening. you are uploading your file to a location in your server, and then storing the location of your file in your database. If its an image, then a simple query to get the location from your database, and then putting that link into a <img src="$dbPath"> for example will display the image from the database. Pay attention boi

Comment: Storing into the database is pain staking in itself, because then you have to write extra code to encode the image again, which as been stored in your db as a long list of random letters numbers and characters, please take the easier way out